# Table over-laps div when using position:absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I'm trying to create a column locking effect on a table. However, when the I lock the columns they flow out of (appear on top of) the parent div.

I've tried setting the `zIndex` of column data and parent div, which causes the div to appear on top of the columns. **However, the portion of the columns that are bigger than the viewport still appear outside the div.**

I'm almost certain this is a problem with `position:absolute;` and how it removes elements from the document flow, but I can't quite figure out a way that doesn't use `position:absolute`. What I'd like to understand what is causing the overlap problem and how to fix it with plain old html / css / js.

**By the way, I'm not looking for a jQuery plug in solution to create locked table columns.**

```
<style>
  table {
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  .data-table td {
    border-top: 1px solid;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 74px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
  }

  .data-table {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }

  .col-header {
    width: 74px;
  }

  .container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="data-table" id="column-data-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td data-column-index="0">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 1 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="1">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 2 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="2">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 3 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="3">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 4 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="4">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 5 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="5">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 6 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="6">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 7 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="7">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 8 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="8">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 9 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="9">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 10 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="10">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 11 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="11">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 12 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
          <td data-column-index="12">
            <div class="col-header"> Column 13 </div>
            <div onclick="lockColumns(event);"> Lock </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td> Data 1 </td>
          <td> Data 2</td>
          <td> Data 3</td>
          <td> Data 4</td>
          <td> Data 5</td>
          <td> Data 6</td>
          <td> Data 7</td>
          <td> Data 8</td>
          <td> Data 9</td>
          <td> Data 10</td>
          <td> Data 11</td>
          <td> Data 12</td>
          <td> Data 13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Data 1 </td>
          <td> Data 2</td>
          <td> Data 3</td>
          <td> Data 4</td>
          <td> Data 5</td>
          <td> Data 6</td>
          <td> Data 7</td>
          <td> Data 8</td>
          <td> Data 9</td>
          <td> Data 10</td>
          <td> Data 11</td>
          <td> Data 12</td>
          <td> Data 13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Data 1 </td>
          <td> Data 2</td>
          <td> Data 3</td>
          <td> Data 4</td>
          <td> Data 5</td>
          <td> Data 6</td>
          <td> Data 7</td>
          <td> Data 8</td>
          <td> Data 9</td>
          <td> Data 10</td>
          <td> Data 11</td>
          <td> Data 12</td>
          <td> Data 13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Data 1 </td>
          <td> Data 2</td>
          <td> Data 3</td>
          <td> Data 4</td>
          <td> Data 5</td>
          <td> Data 6</td>
          <td> Data 7</td>
          <td> Data 8</td>
          <td> Data 9</td>
          <td> Data 10</td>
          <td> Data 11</td>
          <td> Data 12</td>
          <td> Data 13</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    function lockColumns(e) {
      let columnDataTable = window.document.getElementById("column-data-table");
      let columnDataRows = columnDataTable.rows;
      let colWidths = new Array(columnDataRows[0].children[0].length);

      for (var j = 0; j < columnDataRows.length; j++) {
        let currentCell = e.target.parentNode;
        let currentColInd = currentCell.dataset.columnIndex;

        for (let i = 0; i <= currentColInd; i++) {
          columnDataRows[j].children[i].style.position = "absolute";
          if (i > 0) {
            let prevColPosition = (i - 1);
            if (!colWidths[i]) {
              let prevColBoundingRect = columnDataRows[j].children[prevColPosition].getBoundingClientRect();
              colWidths[i] = prevColBoundingRect.x + prevColBoundingRect.width;
            }
            let prevColPos = colWidths[i];

            columnDataRows[j].children[i].style.left = prevColPos + "px";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/yd1cjuo8/9/)

Comment: you say you set the z-index on the parent div, but did you also set its position to something other than static (i.e. `position: relative;`)? z-index only works on positioned elements

Comment: I think you will have a hard time trying to control the overflow of something thats not in the document flow when the parent is. [This is a little closer](https://jsfiddle.net/yd1cjuo8/14/) but still not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the overlap. However, my column locking is broken now.

Comment: Thats because your cells are position absolute... you would have to change them to fixed. See my fiddle in my previous comment

Comment: If it's hard to control the overflow with position:absolute, can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: What you are trying to do is actually pretty difficult, if not impossible with pure css. I would recommend finding a javascript plugin that solves this problem instead of trying to create your own (people have probably already solved this problem). For instance, datatables is a popular table plugin and it does have a [fixed column extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll take a look at it